# Qt: can't solve error: multiple definition

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

So I have google this problem and search this site but everything I have found does not work. Here are the troublesome lines in the header file:

```
ChartView(QChart *chart, QWidget *parent = 0);
QLineSeries *hLine;
QLineSeries *vLine;
bool isDoneDrawing;
void doneDrawing(bool newValue);
```

This is the header file:

```
 #ifndef CHARTVIEW_H
 #define CHARTVIEW_H

 #include <QtCharts/QChartView>
 #include <QtWidgets>
 #include <QtCharts>

 QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE


 class ChartView : public QChartView
 {
 public:
     ChartView(QChart *chart, QWidget *parent = 0);
     QLineSeries *hLine;
     QLineSeries *vLine;
     bool isDoneDrawing;
     void doneDrawing(bool newValue);

 protected:
     void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

 };

 #endif
```

and this is the ccp file:

```
    #include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtCharts>
#include "chartview.h"

ChartView::ChartView(QChart *chart, QWidget *parent) :
    QChartView(chart, parent){
    isDoneDrawing = false;
    hLine = new QLineSeries();
    hLine->setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::white), 0.5, Qt::DotLine));
    chart->addSeries(hLine);
    //this->chart()->addSeries(hLine);

    vLine = new QLineSeries();
    vLine->setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::white), 0.5, Qt::DotLine));
    chart->addSeries(vLine);
    //this->chart()->addSeries(vLine);

    setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);



}

void ChartView::doneDrawing(bool newValue){
    isDoneDrawing = newValue;
}

void ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    if(isDoneDrawing){
        //draw horizontal line
        double y = double(event->pos().y());
        if(y < this->chart()->plotArea().bottom() && y > this->chart()->plotArea().top()){
            this->chart()->removeSeries(hLine);
            double min = this->chart()->property("yMin").toDouble();
            double max = this->chart()->property("yMax").toDouble();
            //rescale y
            y = (max-min)*(y-this->chart()->plotArea().top())/(this->chart()->plotArea().bottom()-this->chart()->plotArea().top())+min;
            //invert y
            y= (max+min)-y;
            hLine->clear();
            hLine->append(0,y);
            hLine->append(this->chart()->plotArea().right(),y);
            hLine->append(this->chart()->size().width(),y);
            this->chart()->addSeries(hLine);
            hLine->attachAxis(this->chart()->axisY());
            hLine->attachAxis(this->chart()->axisX());
        }

        //draw vertical line
        double x = double(event->pos().x());
        if(x < this->chart()->plotArea().right() && x > this->chart()->plotArea().left()){
            this->chart()->removeSeries(vLine);
            double min = this->chart()->property("xMin").toDouble();
            double max = this->chart()->property("xMax").toDouble();
            //rescale x
            x = (max-min)*(x-this->chart()->plotArea().right())/(this->chart()->plotArea().left()-this->chart()->plotArea().right())+min;


            //update price info in title
            QStringList data = this->chart()->property(QString::number((int)x).toUtf8()).toString().split(',');
            QString title;
            QString dataColor = this->chart()->series().at(0)->property(QString::number((int)x).toUtf8()).toString();
            title = this->chart()->property("newTitle").toString().append("<table  style='color:"+dataColor+"; font-size:10px'><tr><td width='100'>Date:<br>").append(data[0]);
            title.append("</td><td width='50'>Open:<br>").append(data[3]);
            title.append("</td><td width='50'>High:<br>").append(data[4]);
            title.append("</td><td width='50'>Low:<br>").append(data[1]);
            title.append("</td><td width='50'>Close:<br>").append(data[2]);
            title.append("</td><td width='50'>High:<br>").append(data[5]);
            title.append("</td><td width='50'>Low:<br>").append(data[6]);
            if(data.size() > 7){
                title.append("</td><td width='50'>PC:<br>").append(data[7]);
            }else{
                title.append("</td><td width='50'>PC:<br>");
            }
            title.append("</td></tr></table>");
            this->chart()->setTitle(title);


            //invert x
            x= (max+min)-x;
            vLine->clear();
            vLine->append(x,this->chart()->size().height());
            vLine->append(x,0);
            this->chart()->addSeries(vLine);
            vLine->attachAxis(this->chart()->axisY());
            vLine->attachAxis(this->chart()->axisX());
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding extern before each declaration and can't find where I am missing the ';' at the end of a line. Any help would be great. I am using a fresh install of Ubuntu and Qt Creator.  This project has been imported from my prior install.

Hope this is enough info. Many of the other questions on this error were lacking info so I hope this question will solve that also.

Here is the error codes:

> /home/bandito/programming/build-etf-ipo-new-Unnamed-Debug/chartview.o:-1: In function `QList<QtCharts::QAbstractSeries*>::node_destruct(QList<QtCharts::QAbstractSeries*>::Node*, QList<QtCharts::QAbstractSeries*>::Node*)':
>   /home/bandito/programming/etf-ipo-new/chartview.cpp:5: error: multiple definition of`ChartView::ChartView(QtCharts::QChart*, QWidget*)'
>   /home/bandito/programming/etf-ipo-new/chartview.cpp:5: first defined here
>   /home/bandito/programming/build-etf-ipo-new-Unnamed-Debug/chartview.o:-1: In function
>   `QList<QtCharts::QAbstractSeries*>::node_destruct(QList<QtCharts::QAbstractSeries*>::Node*,
>   QList<QtCharts::QAbstractSeries*>::Node*)':
>   /home/bandito/programming/etf-ipo-new/chartview.cpp:5: error: multiple definition of`
>   ChartView::ChartView(QtCharts::QChart*, QWidget*)'
>   /home/bandito/programming/etf-ipo-new/chartview.cpp:5: first defined here
>   /home/bandito/programming/build-etf-ipo-new-Unnamed-Debug/chartview.o:-1: In function
>   `ChartView::doneDrawing(bool)':
>   /home/bandito/programming/etf-ipo-new/chartview.cpp:24: error: multiple definition of`
>   ChartView::doneDrawing(bool)'
>   /home/bandito/programming/etf-ipo-new/chartview.cpp:24: first defined here
>   /home/bandito/programming/build-etf-ipo-new-Unnamed-Debug/chartview.o:-1: In function
>   `ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)':
>   /home/bandito/programming/etf-ipo-new/chartview.cpp:28: error: multiple definition of`
>   ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)'
>   /home/bandito/programming/etf-ipo-new/chartview.cpp:28: first defined here
>   :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: can you show the error message?

Comment: Any chance that you accidentally added ChartView.cpp to your .pro/project file twice?

Comment: Working in VS2013, I once accidentally included a ".cc" instead of the ".h" and hence got duplicated symbols. (_May be_, Intellisence tricked me - wouldn't be the first time. May be, I simply was sleepy and "absent in mind".) Because I would never do this intentionally I needed a certain time until I recognized it.

Comment: Jeremy Friesner: You were right.  Actually I had chartview.h and chartview.cpp in the pro file twice.  Now I am getting one error "error: No rule to make target '/chartview.cpp', needed by 'chartview.o'.  Stop.".  Back to more trouble shooting.